# Cordova - How to save mp4 to Camera Roll (ios)

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I am building a hybrid app using Cordova.
It generates mp4s using ffmpeg.js, the output is a blob.
The blob is then written to disk using cordova-plugin-file.

The problem is i can't find the mp4 within the Camera Roll once downloaded.
The following code appears to run correctly, not throwing any errors and reaching the onwriteend function. I am also confident the mp4 isn't corrupt.

```
const myVideoBlob = new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'video/mp4' })
let folderPath = Env.ios ? window.cordova.file.documentsDirectory : window.cordova.file.externalDataDirectory
let filename = 'video.mp4'

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(folderPath, (dir) => {
    console.log("got main dir", dir);
    dir.getFile(filename, {
            create: true
        }, (file) => {
            console.log("got the file", file);
            file.createWriter(

                (fileWriter) => {

                    fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
                        console.log("onwriteend :: success writing file");
                    };

                    fileWriter.onerror = function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    };

                    fileWriter.write(myVideoBlob);

                },
                (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            )

        },

        (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
},

(err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

After further investigation i found the mp4s were indeed being saved to the App's documents folder, as intended

It was my misunderstanding that these mp4s would be viewable in the ios Library / Photos App, under the videos category or even its own album folder.

Anyone know if this functionality is possible using the cordova-plugin-file?

Comment: Hi Cam, I'm also looking for a solution to this. Have you found one yet?

Comment: Hey, i ended up using > https://github.com/tien271/cordova-plugin-photo-library-wkwebview . Not an ideal solution, given the lack of community support.

Comment: @Luxapodular - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/398#issuecomment-651432022

Comment: Thanks for following up with this. So there is no way to do this in just stock cordova-plugin-file?